# Can answers deleted as a consequence of a deleted question affect the answer ban algorithm?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, post-ban

I wrote an answer to a question. After sometime, the question was deleted by the user himself and as a result my answer also got deleted.

After researching about deleted answers, I came to know that the answer ban algorithm will keep track of users whose answers get deleted (either by himself or by some others who found it wrong) and the system internally leaves a black mark on the one who wrote the answer and if the same user's answers keep getting deleted, then he will eventually get banned from answering questions.

However, in my case no one deleted my answer directly.

Does the system consider my answer as "deleted by someone" and has the chance of me getting an answer ban increased? If not then why is there an option to undelete my answer exists?

Comment: No, there is no "black mark".  The system only looks at downvotes.  You cannot yourself undelete the answer since the questioner deleted his.  Flagging a moderator and asking for the question to be restored is entirely normal and expected.

Comment: The option to undelete my answer should not appear on the UI. Isn't that a bug?

Comment: That's another question, covered many times before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely, they don't.

E.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160382/pass-the-result-of-array-as-an-argument ([<10k link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gYP.png)), the answer is marked just "deleted", not "deleted by <user(s)>" as usual.

This suggests that the system recognizes this as a special case.

Answer (score 5):

The only things we know about the ban system:

- *All* posts count for and against you, including those which are deleted.
- Depending on the circumstance, a post which is deleted may become one which you are unable to actually fix and get undeleted (e.g. if you had an entire question deleted, or your post was deleted by a moderator, etc).

So yes, if your post was deemed by the system to be poor, then it would count against you, irrespective of who deleted it or how.

Comment: This question is about whether or not the system considers the fact that an answer is deleted in the answer ban algorithm.

Comment: @gparyani:  Did I *not* answer that?

Comment: Votes always count towards answer bans regardless of deletion, but the *fact* that an answer is deleted can also count. For instance, for questions deleted more than 30 days after being asked, the fact that it's deleted doesn't count, but the votes still count.

Comment: No, the fact that the post is deleted *doesn't* really count.  From everything that I've read and have answered on this subject, the fact that a post is deleted only means that the post *may* not be able to be fixed (e.g. one can't go back to edit their posts 'into shape' since it may never be resurrected).  It doesn't add any extra weight to the post.  The votes count irrespective of if it's deleted or not, which I made clear above.